Do different idempotent functions $f,g:\{1,\ldots,n\} \to \{1,\ldots,n\}$ exist such that $f \circ g = f$ and $|\mathrm{ran}(f)|=|\mathrm{ran}(g)|$?
During my study, I've come up with the following question. Are there functions $f,g:\{1,\ldots,n\} \to \{1,\ldots,n\}$ (for some $n$) such that

$f \circ f = f$, $g \circ g = g$;
$f \circ g = f$;
$|\mathrm{ran}(f)|=|\mathrm{ran}(g)|$;
$f \ne g$.

Here $\mathrm{ran}(h) = \{h(i) \mid i=1,\ldots,n\}$.
For example, if one takes $n=2k$, $g(i)=i$ for all $i$ and $f(i)=2 \lceil i/2 \rceil$, then these functions satisfy all the requirements except for 3 because $|\mathrm{ran}(f)| = k \ne 2k = |\mathrm{ran}(g)|$.
Maybe the answer is obvious but I'm not that sure...

Please do not answer in the comments.

Take for example $f$ defined $f(i)=1$ for each $i \in \{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ and $g(i)=2$ for each $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$. Then it is straightforward to check that $f \circ g = f \circ f = f$, whle $g \circ g=g$.
